# What does self do inside a Python array embedded in a Class?

Tags: python

```
def traverse(self):
    print("Traversing...")
    nodes_to_visit = [self]
    while len(nodes_to_visit) != 0:
        current_node = nodes_to_visit.pop()
        print(current_node.value)
        nodes_to_visit += current_node.children
```

I have this function inside a class(I'm learning Data Structures), and on the third line, there's a self inside an array, that is then used. What does it do, what does it return? (And while asking, are Data Structures advanced? Can I consider my self an 'advanced' programmer now ;)?)

Comment: `self` is the same thing it would be anywhere else in the method - it's the instance on which `traverse` is being called.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Data Structures can be indeed advance. Most likely it involves performance for processing many data like thousands and millions. You will learn terms like run time complexity `O(n)`, `log(n)`.

An example benefit of having good knowledge in Data Structure is when you parse an excel file that contains a million rows. I have a colleage that made a script that took an hour to finish the job while mine only took 5 minutes.

Take note that the most basic data structure for python is the dictionary.. It is always `O(n)` runtime complexity